# Determining win streaks in data

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I know there are other posts on finding winning streaks in data, and a mate and I have used them to come up with the following code... the problem is my database is nearly 20,000 rows and when looking for a streak where a team has played over 500 games (which is most teams) the script takes a very long time to run and eventually times out.  I was hoping this code could be made more efficient so I can return the output on my website and avoid server timeout issues. Where a team has played a smaller number of games the query works as expected and only takes between 2-20 seconds to appear.

The table includes these columns

```
ID | GameID | TeamID | Team | Opponent | WL
```

The ID is the unique identifier, the GameID is the game number and TeamID is the game number for that particular team.

```
 $query =  "  

  SELECT C.WL, C.StartDate,
    (SELECT Team FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.StartDate AND Team = '$Team') AS Club,
    (SELECT GameID FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.StartDate AND Team = '$Team') AS StartStreakGameID ,
    (SELECT Opponent FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.StartDate AND Team = '$Team') AS StartStreakOpposition ,
    (SELECT RoundNo FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.StartDate AND Team = '$Team') AS StartRoundNo,
    (SELECT Season FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.StartDate AND Team = '$Team') AS StartSeason, 
    C.EndDate,
    (SELECT GameID FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.EndDate AND Team = '$Team') AS EndStreakGameID ,
    (SELECT Opponent FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.EndDate AND Team = '$Team') AS EndStreakOpposition ,
    (SELECT RoundNo FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.EndDate AND Team = '$Team') AS EndRoundNo,
    (SELECT Season FROM MatchDetails WHERE TeamID = C.EndDate AND Team = '$Team') AS EndSeason,
    C.Games

        FROM 

        (SELECT B.WL,B.StartDate,B.EndDate,B.Games
     FROM 
      (SELECT WL, MIN(TeamID) as StartDate, MAX(TeamID) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games FROM 
      (SELECT TeamID, WL, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MatchDetails G WHERE G.WL <> GR.WL AND G.TeamID <= GR.TeamID AND Team = '$Team') 
                as  RunGroup FROM MatchDetails GR WHERE Team = '$Team')  A 
     GROUP BY WL, RunGroup ORDER BY (Games))
    B WHERE WL = 'W' AND Games > 1 ORDER BY (Games) DESC LIMIT 10 ) C";
```

Above is the SQL - Below is the PHP output and usage.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result) ;
            if($numrows > 0)
            {
            echo "<table class = tablescores>
            <tr>
            <th>Wins</th>
                    <th align=left>Team</th>
            <th align=left>Start Opponent</th>
            <th>Start Game</th>
            <th align=left>End Opponent</th>
            <th>End Game</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {
                $venues = 'venues';
                echo "<tr class=$venues>";
                echo "<td align=center width=10%>".$row['Games']."</td>";            
                echo "<td width=20%>"."<a href='teamidx.php?Team=".$row['Club']."'>".$row['Club']."</td>";
                echo "<td width=20%>"."<a href='teamidx.php?Team=".$row['StartStreakOpposition']."'>".$row['StartStreakOpposition']."</td>";
                echo "<td align=center width=15%>"."<a href='gamestats.php?GameID=".$row['GameID']."'>".$row['StartRoundNo'].",".$row['StartSeason']."</td>";   
                echo "<td width=20%>"."<a href='teamidx.php?Team=".$row['EndStreakOpposition']."'>".$row['EndStreakOpposition']."</td>";
                echo "<td align=center width=15%>"."<a href='gamestats.php?GameID=".$row['GameID']."'>".$row['EndRoundNo'].",".$row['EndSeason']."</td>";       
             }
                echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: as far as I understand it, try declaring the JOINs rather than using the shorthand `,` . I read a few articles how SQL is trying to move away from the `,` operator for joins . Also reference all your names by `<table>.<column>` as you've only done this with some names in the query.

Comment: Hi Martin - any chance you can give me an idea on how to declare the JOINs in my example rather than using the , shorthand?

Comment: I have given you an answer but the more I look at the SQL the more I think it should be split into multiple smaller Queries

Comment: Efficiency may also be increased by indexing the most useful columns in your table, are your tables indexed properly?

Answer (score 1):

How to improve JOINs on a SQL query:

Use something like this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg to improve your joins from commas (`,`) to full `JOIN` statements, there are various types of joines available:

[image: SQL Join Types]

Please note that with the diagram - it is possible to do a join without having to declare `TableA A` this can be simplified just to remain as `Table A` so:

The image in the top left of the diagram can be slightly reduced to:

```
SELECT <...> FROM TABLEA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Key = TableB.Key
```

There may be reasons to avoid doing this in some cases but that is beyond the scope of this answer (*and my current knowledge*).

My first/main thought is why can you not split this into multiple smaller queries? I think overall that may be the better way of improving this.

Otherwise choose the type of JOIN you want to use for the type of result you want, this should improve your efficiency a little.

Extra Note:
Also setting indexes on columns would be a big help to you, if you've not done so already.